# Bind to Combo box based on Data Gridview selection

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this problem;

**int gender = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
cmbGender.SelectedValue = gender;**

1. I saved values to a different table in my database using the ID of values from another table.
2. I want to retrieve the name instead of the ID of the value from my database and bind to a combo box. The combo Box already has selections from the Database.
3. The code above gives me female for the first selection from my data gridview into the combo box. And male is given for the second selection.
4. When I move to the third row in my table, no gender is selected.
5. The first selection does not correspond with the exact record in the database either.
   I need your help

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question: what happens if, instead of `cmbGender.SelectedValue = gender` you use `cmbGender.SelectedIndex = gender`?

Comment: The idea is to get the value that is in the database (Which is already passed to my datagridview) to be on set to my combo box once i click a particular cell in the datagridview. SelectedIndex did not do it for me. I am using a storedProcedure to send and retrieve my records.

Comment: @IsaacZahn can you publish the relevant part from your code? it will be much easy to answer this question.

Comment: private void dtGrdAdd_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
{ DataGridViewRow row = this.dtGrdAdd.Rows[e.RowIndex];
//This part only gets the first and second items bound to the combobox. 
//it does not bind the item from the gridview to the combo
int gender = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
cmbGender.SelectedValue = gender;                
            }
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

Its quite hard to help you because you did not publish all the relevant parts of your code in an organized manner.
 i see you are new here please read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

because there are missing parts in your question i will make some assumptions.
**please try to understand the principals of my answer**.

1. I assume you use `Datatable` in order to retrieve data from database.
2. I assume that column names are "ID" and "Gender"
3. I assume that Gender has the values of 0 (male) and 1 ("female").
4. I assume that your combobox values are "MALE" and "FEMALE"

i suggest to use dictionary in order to get the gender of the ID in each `Cellclick` event

please read comments inside the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetDataFromDataBase();
}

Dictionary<int, int> IdGenderDict;
private void GetDataFromDataBase()
{
    // get data from database
    DataTable dt = DAL.DataBase.GetData();
    // set datagridview
    dtGrdAdd.DataSource = dt;
    // initilize dictionary that willl hold key value pair for ID against its gender
    IdGenderDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    // set the dictionary
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        IdGenderDict.Add(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString()),
        Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Gender"].ToString()));
    }
}

private void dtGrdAdd_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // get the selected id from the datagridview
    var id = Convert.ToInt32(this.dtGrdAdd.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].ToString());
    // find the gender using the dictionary
    var gender = IdGenderDict[id];
    // set the combobox with the gender
    if (gender == 0)
    {
        cmbGender.SelectedItem = "MALE";
    }
    else
    {
        cmbGender.SelectedItem = "FEMALE";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
DataTable dt = DAL.DataBase.GetData();
What will DAL.database.GetaData() be doing. I am mainly interested in the function of the DAL

Comment: `DAL` is a convention name for a project that is handling database operations (its not a system namespace), i assumed that you have a project that handles database calls - if not its a good practice to separate data layer from business logic and presentation layer, please read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx. also if this answers your question please mark it as an answer by clicking the check mark icon (-:

Answer (score 0):

From Databse via storedProcedure:
Gender.ID AS GenderID,
      Gender.Gender,

INNER JOIN Gender ON Gender.ID = Staff.Gender

In WinForms:

private void dtGrdAdd_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

//gets a collection that contains all the rows
`DataGridViewRow row = this.dtGrdAdd.Rows[e.RowIndex];`

// row.Cells[4].Value represents the index of the Row on the DataGridView
`int gender = int.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
            cmbGender.SelectedValue = gender;`

}